# pandas dataframe to django database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pandas, dataframe

I need to create an SQL table (sqlite3) from a pandas dataframe inside django. this is the code I'm using:

```
from django.db import connection
import pandas as pd
# ....
pf = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Mike', 'Chris', 'Alex']})
pf.to_sql(name='customers', con=dj, if_exists='replace')
```

But all I'm getting is this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1681, in execute
    cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\contextlib.py", line 88, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 113, in debug_sql
    sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
  File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\operations.py", line 160, in last_executed_query
    return sql % params
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\django_sandbox\polls\models.py", line 32, in go_big
    pf.to_sql(name='go_big', con=dj, if_exists='replace')
  File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2615, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 598, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1827, in to_sql
    table.create()
  File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 721, in create
    if self.exists():
  File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 708, in exists
    return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
  File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1838, in has_table
    return len(self.execute(query, [name]).fetchall()) > 0
  File "F:\Programming\Python\Django\sandbox\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1693, in execute
    raise ex from exc
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Any idea how to fix this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the type of database you are using and the structure of the model that `customers` is mapped to, please

Comment: just did @Danoram